# Very fast URL check

Tags: java, android, performance, url

So I creating an android app where I need to check if a file exist on a remote server really fast because I have to test ~1000 links before the app become usable.

I currently call a function that return the URL if it's valid and `null` if not.

```
public String CheckUrl(String url) {
  try {
    URL urll = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) urll.openConnection();

    huc.setRequestMethod("GET");  //OR  huc.setRequestMethod ("HEAD");
    huc.connect();
    int code = huc.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(code);

    if (code == 200) {
      return url;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
for (Element episode : episodes) {
  globalEpisodeCounter++;
  localEpisodeCounter++;

  MLP_Episode currentEpisode = new MLP_Episode();

  Elements links = episode.getElementsByTag("a");
  Element linkObj = links.get(0);
  Element thumObj = linkObj.getElementsByTag("img").get(0);
  Element titleObj = linkObj.getElementsByTag("b").get(0);

  int notRealsead = episode.getElementsByClass("btn btn-sm btn-error").size();
  Boolean epReleased = false;
  if (notRealsead == 0) {
    epReleased = true;
  }

  currentEpisode.url = "https://www.newlunarrepublic.fr" + linkObj.attributes().get("href");
  currentEpisode.thumbUrl = "https://www.newlunarrepublic.fr" + thumObj.attributes().get("src");
  currentEpisode.title = titleObj.text();
  currentEpisode.released = epReleased;
  currentEpisode.id_local = localEpisodeCounter;
  currentEpisode.id_global = globalEpisodeCounter;
  currentEpisode.in_season_num = seasonCounter;

  if (epReleased) {
    currentEpisode.url_vo_1080p = CheckUrl(
        "---------/NLR-1080p-" + addZero(seasonCounter) + "x" + addZero(localEpisodeCounter) + ".webm");

  }

  epList.add(currentEpisode);
}
```

At the and end of the search the search thread call a function to update UI

But the down side of the function is that it's very slow 1-2 link/sec which ranslate in 15min waiting before the app is usable

Comment: why does resuming the app depend on this?

Comment: it display the avalible episodes for play them but I find a solution

Comment: You could try pinging the url, which might (maybe) be faster. You could also spread the load and check a few links at the same time. Also, you should show the user that the app is working in some way if it still takes forever, with something like progress bar.

Answer (score -1):

So the answer was to run the check in a separate thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            currentEpisode.url_vo_1080p = CheckUrl("------------/NLR-1080p-"+addZero(seasonCounter2)+"x"+addZero(localEpisodeCounter2)+".webm");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }
};

thread.start();
```

Comment: how can this fix the issue, if you need the data before resuming?

Comment: It's a lot faster (1sec) and I don't need the data before I need it after

Comment: *I have to test ~1000 links before the app become usable.* - here you said you need it before

Comment: yes because if I don't have the links I cant update the ui for the user the searching thread calls a function after all check are terminated for that